# Get neo4j result

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

I'm using neo4j jdbc driver to access a local service and make the following query to find what I need:

```
"MATCH (u:User)-->(d:Deck)-[p:Played]->(g:Game)" +
"WHERE id(g) = ?" +
"RETURN {r {user :u, deck :d, played:p, game:g}}"
```

I cast it as a map and can find the parts and, right there in my face, I can see the stuff I need. How do I get it? (the {comment= ...} etc)

[image]

I do know how to get it by

```
RETURN p.comment, p.place ... etc
```

But I fear this will soon get out of hand. If I can just get at least that json string I would be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in Cypher function `PROPERTIES()`, outlined [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-properties), that will convert anything that has properties (nodes, relationships, even pre-existing Maps) to a Map of the properties with no other data. The language drivers have built-in tools to `hydrate` Nodes and Relationships so that property access is simple, but if you require a Map and only a Map to be returned, just use `RETURN PROPERTIES(p)` and you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, it looks like you are trying to get all the properties of specific nodes and properties, without any extraneous metadata.

After installing the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) plugin, you can use the `apoc.map.fromPairs` procedure to generate a map with all the properties of a node or relationship.

For example, to get all the properties of every `User` node:

```
MATCH (u:User)
CALL apoc.map.fromPairs([k IN KEYS(u) | [k, u[k]]]) YIELD value AS props
RETURN props;
```

- `[k IN KEYS(u) | [k, u[k]]]` generates a collection of key/value collections.
- The `apoc.map.fromPairs()` procedure takes a collection of key/value collections, and converts it into a map.

Comment: This certainly doesn't look like a bad option but as I could solve my problem without any external dependencies I favoured that answer.

Comment: Yes, the `PROPERTIES()` function would be the best answer, now that I know about it. It seems to have been added recently, and is not even in the [Cheat Sheet](http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) yet.